# Java: Generic type casting, how can I fix this so I don't suppress the unchecked warning

Tags: java, generics, casting, extends, unchecked-cast

```
private static transient JavaPlugin myPlugin = null;

public SomeClass(JavaPlugin plugin) {
    if (myPlugin == null) myPlugin = plugin;
}

public <T> T getPlugin(Class<? extends JavaPlugin> plugin) {
    return (T)myPlugin; // return casted version of "myPlugin" form above
}
```

Calling it in the line below works just fine, and trying to use a class that doesn't extend JavaPlugin will throw a compile time error. But how can I make it so the above function works without requiring `@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")`??

```
MyPlugin nc = this.getPlugin(my.main.package.MyPlugin.class);
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are aware that you are actually returning a `Class` instance from your method, and storing it in a reference of type `MyPlugin`? So, you are actually assigning `Class<MyPlugin>` instance to `MyPlugin`. that is not going to work.

To workaround with that, you have to use `Class#newInstance()` method to return an instance of that class you are passing. And make the parameter type `Class<T>`:

```
public <T extends MyPlugin> T getPlugin(Class<T> plugin) {
    return plugin.newInstance();
}
```

Well, I've just given you an idea of what you were doing wrong. You have to handle appropriate exceptions, and also check if the class you are passing has a 0-arg constructor, else it won't work.

Comment: Sorry I seem to have left out something crucial. I will not know that "MyPlugin" exists, I need to cast my class level variable `myPlugin` of type `JavaPlugin` to the type `Class<T> plugin`.

Comment: @BrianGraham You mean to say, you want to perform down-casting here? Look out for `Class.cast` method.

Comment: Thanks, figured it out now. I'll accept this as answering both of my questions. :)